# Editing files within a Debian distribution ISO image on macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, iso-image, macos-ventura

I need to modify a few files in the Debian 11.6 distribution ISO to enable installation over a serial console. Is there a way I can do this on a MacBook running macOS Ventura?

Comment: If you can extract the ISO contents, do the edits you want and repackage the ISO then the OS doesn't matter as long as it has the required tools. Perhaps you should be asking a more specific question?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I downloaded the iso image and then extracted it on my Mac using Keka. I've modified the files to enable serial console. I can repackage these files using Keka again but I'm not sure if it will be a bootable disk .

Comment: Have you tried? Please edit your question and make it more complete.

Answer (score 2):

I got help from the developers of Keka and I'm replicating their [answer](https://github.com/aonez/Keka/discussions/1246) below. Once you've made the changes, Keka does not repackage the ISO while retaining its bootable status. However, you can use `xorriso` to do the same.

```
xorriso -as mkisofs \
    -V 'debian-11.6' \
    -e boot/grub/efi.img \
    -no-emul-boot \
    -o <YOUR_DESTINATION.iso> \
    <YOUR_DEBIAN_FOLDER>
```